# How many threads is DuckDB using?

Tags: r, duckdb

Using duckDB from within R, e.g.

```
library(duckdb)
dbname <- "sparsemat.duckdb"
con2 <- dbConnect(duckdb(), dbname)
dbExecute(con2, "PRAGMA memory_limit='1GB';")
```

how can I find out how many threads the (separate process) is using? I am aware of

```
dbExecute(con2, "PRAGMA threads=4;")
```

but I am interested in figuring out reading this configuration detail, not setting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below query will read the configuration

```
-- show a list of all available settings
SELECT * FROM duckdb_settings();

-- return the current value of a specific setting
SELECT current_setting('threads')
```